# How to get the first day month of X months ago in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

In Hive it's easy to get the day of X months later with `add_months`, but how do I do the opposite?
Is there something like this in Hive?
`sub_months("2018-03-11", 4) == "2017-11-11"`

Comment: Did you try negative values like `add_months('2018-03-11',-4)`?

Comment: @Bala Thanks a lot! You saved me from pulling my hair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get X months ago of a given month, you have just to add minus, for example:

```
select add_months('2018-03-11',-4);
```